# iterate through rows and cells using for loop in c# Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have already checked many answers but all are using a `foreach` loop to iterate through rows. I want to use a `for` loop.

**Code:**

```
IWebElement NtTable = driver.FindElement(By.Id("nt-item-table"));
IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> TableRows = NtTable.FindElements(By.TagName("tr")).ToList();

for (int i = 0; i <= TableRows.Count; i++)
{
    //driver.FindElement(TableRows[i])....
    //Tablows.get(i)....

}
```

I tried above commented 2 lines to get text of particular TD from particular TR but seems not getting any property after press `(.)`. Above seems fine if I use Java but not in C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues.

1. You don't need to chain the `.FindElement()` calls. It's more efficient to just get the `TR`s in one search, e.g. by CSS selector `#nt-item-table tr`.
2. You are calling `.ToList()` after the `.FindElements()` call which isn't necessary and won't work. It shows an error in the IDE.
3. You are iterating to `<= TableRows.Count` when you only need `<`. The index starts at 0.
4. You can't access elements in the `IReadOnlyCollection` using array notation, e.g. `TableRows[i]`. You need to use `LINQ` and `ElementAt(i)`.
5. You already have found the `TR` elements, statements like `driver.FindElement(TableRows[i])....` make no sense.
6. `Tablows` is not a variable name that you have defined. The variable is `TableRows`.

   ```
   IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> TableRows = Driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("#nt-item-table tr"));
   for (int i = 0; i < TableRows.Count; i++)
   {
       // do something with TableRows.ElementAt(i);
   }
   ```

You really should spend some time reading some Selenium and basic C# programming tutorials, syntax references, etc. It will help you avoid a lot of these issues.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the variables to start [lowercase (camelcase)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions) and have you tried this. Since you already have a list of tr elements which have child elements (td)

```
IWebElement ntTable = driver.FindElement(By.Id("nt-item-table"));
IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> tableRows = ntTable.FindElements(By.TagName("tr")).ToList();

for (int i = 0; i <= tableRows.Count; i++)
{
    var tdCollection = tableRows[i].FindElements(By.TagName("td"));

    for (int c = 0; c <= tdCollection.Count; c++)
    {
        string column = tdCollection[c].Text;
    }
}
```

I would prefer [foreach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38682184/169714) though. Because you do not need index int's then.

Comment: Should I declare `IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> tdCollection` like this just before loop?

Comment: Or in the 1st loop like I just edited with `var`. Or strong typed, what you prefer.